# Fantasy manga/comic about a teenager in another world with both lightning and fire powers, and a necklace boosting his training speed

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga

- it is about a teen who, after visiting an old man he knew, gets a necklace which transports him to another world
- the world in question has magic that people first activate in school and he activates lighting and fire but people don't unlock multiple simultaneously
- the necklace he has boosts his training speed and can absorb the power of other training items, as well as the souls of monsters to improve itself

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [Versatile Mage](https://www.readmng.com/versatile-mage).

In the first chapter, the main character Mo Fan receives a necklace from an old man he knows. The old man dies and has Mo Fan bury him on the mountain he lives on.  That night Mo Fan goes to sleep wearing the necklace and wakes up in a world like modern Earth, but with magic instead of science.

In chapters 5 and 6 Mo Fan goes through the process of activating his magic at the school, where he unlocks both lightning and fire. Though no one else sees him activate the lightning as they all ran out of the room to see someone else who had unlocked lightning a few moments before.

In chapters 15-17 the necklace absorbs the power of a training device Mo Fan was given. It is explained to him that his necklace can absorb other training items and can gain power from absorbing monster souls.